# SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function with argon2

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, argon2-ffi

I'm implementing [argon2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/argon2) in my application for password.

```
try {
  if (await argon2.verify("<big long hash>", "password")) {
    // password match
  } else {
    // password did not match
  }
} catch (err) {
  // internal failure
}
```

But getting an error **SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function.**
How can i use async funtion?

Comment: You can only await async function within an async function. e.g `async function verifyPassword(password){ if(await argon2.verify("<big long hash>", "password")){/*...*/} }`

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare an async function with `async` keyword:

```
const myAsyncFunc = async (hashKey, password) => { //<-- declare as an async function
  try {
    if (await argon2.verify(hashKey, password)) {
      // password match
    } else {
      // password did not match
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // internal failure
  }
}

myAsyncFunc("<big long hash>", "password");
```

- Updated answer to make it more verbose

Comment: @iKola, Its not working for me :( , Can I make a helper function(async) using above code?

Comment: @VijayKumar yes, you can create a helper function to do that. You just have to wrap your `await` code inside a function which is declared as `async` function. You cannot run `await` function call without wrapping it into an async function.

Comment: @VijayKumar I updated the answer for a bit to make it more clear how it works.